# Using both RolesAllowed and Transactional in beans

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have some beans which contain methods which are annotated with both @RolesAllowed and @Transactional. I have one Spring config file which utilizes a BeanNameAutoProxyCreator for Security related beans and another Spring config file which utilizes a BeanNameAutoProxyCreator for Transactional related beans.

The problem is that some beans contain both security as well as transactional-related beans. So Spring creates proxies for one set of beans. It then tries to create proxies for the other set of beans. When it does, it tries to create proxies of the proxies and bombs out.

Has anyone tried to configure both security and transactionality in the same beans via Spring? What's the trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it, buy I would look to use one BeanNameAutoProxyCreator that works on both annotation? This BeanNameAutoProxyCreator can create a proxy that delegates to the security and transactional proxies.